# Why can't Mathematica solve this definite integral?

Tags: integral-equations

I want to solve the integral

$\int_{p_0}^{p_1}\left(T_0+\Gamma_p(p_0-p)\right)\frac{1}{p}dp$

Mathematica can do the indefinite integral immediately:

```
>>> Integrate[(T + Γ (p0 - p))*(1/p), p]
-p Γ + (T + p0 Γ) Log[p]
```

But addind bounds suddenly makes it choke, i.e. the following never returns:

```
>>> Integrate[(T + Γ (p0 - p))*(1/p), {p, p0, p1}]
```

even though I can do this just fine:

```
FullSimplify[Limit[-Γ p + (Γ P + T) Log[p], p -> p1] - Limit[-Γ p + (Γ P + T) Log[p], p -> p0]]
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Is the subscript $p$ on $\Gamma$ in the first equation a typo? Is that not the same $p$ as the integration variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Likely this is due to the fact that [antiderivative are troublesome in computer algebra systems](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/). Do this:

```
Integrate[(T + \[CapitalGamma] (p0 - p))*(1/p), {p, p0, p1},   Assumptions -> {p1 > p0 > 0}]
```

Assuming, of course, that `p1 > p0 > 0` is actually true.

Comment: +1 for linking back to that Wolfram blog post.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica likely has problems with four parameters which are assumed to be complex numbers and an antiderivative with branches. The `GenerateConditions -> False/True` option does the job.

```
Integrate[(T + \[CapitalGamma] (p0 - p))*(1/p), {p, p0, p1}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> `p0 - p1) \[CapitalGamma] - (T + p0 \[CapitalGamma]) Log[ p0] + (T + p0 \[CapitalGamma]) Log[p1]`

```
Integrate[(T +\[CapitalGamma] (p0 - p))*(1/p), {p, p0, p1}, 
Assumptions -> {p0, p1, \[CapitalGamma],T} \[Element] Reals,GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(p0 - p1) \[CapitalGamma] + (T +  p0 \[CapitalGamma]) Log[p1/p0], p0 > 0 && p0 != p1 && p1 > 0]`